# Reassigning vector values using nested for-loops in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector, assign

In matlab I have two vectors, ind and ind3. ind = [1 2 3 4 5] and I want to define ind3 based on ind such that I want ind(3), ind(4) and ind(5) to be ind3(1) and ind3(2) and ind3(3). so that ind3 = [ind(3) ind(4) ind(5)] but for some reason I can't do this. I thought it would be simple to do using nested for loops but it doesn't really work.

```
for i=3:5
  for n=1:3
    ind3(n,:) = ind(i,:);
  end 
end
```

By going through the for-loops logically I know why the output is wrong.. but I don't get how else to do it? Am I being stupid and missing something really simple?!

I know its probably a simple answer but can anybody help??

Thanks.

Comment: just write `ind3(1:3,:)=ind(3:5,:)`

Comment: so please make the question a bit more clear, do you want to copy, or shift by 2 columns ?

Comment: @bla no I misunderstood your solution... Its 1.30am and I just misread what you had written.. sorry!! deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ind3 = [ind(3) ind(4) ind(5)] and you want to do it in a loop you just need a single loop. Additionally, since you're dealing with vectors you just have one indexing variable.

```
for n=1:3
  ind3(n) = ind(n + 2);
end
```

Comment: ... Thanks... I don't know why it didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but is this what u want:

```
ind3=ind(3:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you said that your arrays are one dimensional (they are not matrices), and in your code by calling `ind3(n,:)` or `ind(i,:)` you treat them like 2 dimensional arrays.

As long as everything is 1 dimensional here, you need just one for loop:

```
for i=3:5
    ind3(i)=ind(i-2);
end
```

Explanation: here `i=3,4,5`. For `i=3` you assign `ind3[3]=ind[1]`, for `i=4`:  `ind3[4]=ind[2]`,  for `i=5`:  `ind3[5]=ind[3]`.

Or you can simply call `ind3=ind(3:5)`